# How to cope with gap after PhD?

Tags: phd, thesis, postdocs

I submitted my PhD recently and am waiting for the oral examination. Though I have started looking for postdoc positions, the possibility of being without a job, even if for a small period after the viva, is quite frightening. How can I cope with it?

Comment: I'm facing the same situation. You could go on vacation. You could go job hunting. Depending on your skills, you could do a freelancer job.

Comment: Write papers, apply for jobs, relax.

Comment: It is not easy to relax when you have to pay the bills at the end of the month...

Answer (score 7):

One possibility to check about—which I took advantage of at the end of my own graduate career—is that of being hired short-term as a teaching assistant. The good news is that you would have extra time to find a new position. The challenge is that you would be making a commitment to teaching for an additional semester. It would have significant ramifications if you were to  skip out on this duty if you obtained a job offer to start immediately at a company, or a postdoc offer at another university.

Comment: Very good, realistic, useful suggestion.